# Google Speech API metadata doesn't effect the results or conversion method

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am using the following funtion parameters to convert speech to text but the extra parameters i set for metadata parameters doesn't have effect on the conversion result with or without parameters.

function transcribe_async_gcs($bucketName, $objectName, $languageCode = 'en-US', $options = ['enableAutomaticPunctuation'=> true,'enableWordTimeOffsets'=> false,'encoding'=> 'FLAC','sampleRateHertz' => 44100, "metadata"=> [ "interactionType"=> "PHONE_CALL", "industryNaicsCodeOfAudio"=> 621210, "microphoneDistance"=> "NEARFIELD",
    "originalMediaType"=> "AUDIO", "recordingDeviceType"=> "PHONE_LINE", "originalMimeType"=> "audio/mp3", "audioTopic"=> "appointment"],'useEnhanced' => true])

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase speech recognition accuracy, apart from metadata [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/recognition-metadata#available_metadata_fields), you can provide phrase hints with your configuration [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#speechcontext). This may increase the accuracy if you know the context of the speech. There is also an option to use enhanced speech recognition model for better quality results [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/enhanced-models), in which you need to opt-in data logging and be able to use special set of machine learning models. These are all optional fields and regarding to the audio content may or may not have an effect on the results.

Comment: These are the options that you can use to increase accuracy. In case these do not work for you, you need to be more specific about your use case, including what are your results and what change you are expecting to see with providing metadata.

Comment: So i am using all the suggestions you mentioned above. The problem i am facing is that the file transcribed at https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/ doesn't match the result with the result i get through api, eventhough i use the same parameters as them.

Comment: Is [this](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/#streaming_demo_section) the exact link where you are trying the Speech API? In here you can't edit the configuration part and add the metadata you mentioned in your question.